# Call private or protected method from an include file

Tags: php, include, private-methods, class-visibility

*myclass.php*

```
class myclass {

private $name;

public function showData(){
    include_once "extension.php";

    otherFunction($this);

}

private function display(){
    echo "hello world!";
}

}
```

*extension.php*

```
function otherFunction($obj){

    if(isset($obj){
   $obj->display();
    }

}
```

Ok, so this is the issue, for some of you it is *obvious* that I am calling a private method from an include file which obviously will throw an error. My question is:

**1. Is there a way that an include file
    can use external functions to call
    private methods?**

**2. How could I use an included file to
    access private methods and by doing
    so extending my functions to another
    file without making my class file so
    bloated with many functions?**

**3. Is that even possible?**

Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't the included file - the problem is that you are calling a function, which isn't in class scope anymore (the included file by itself is).

Comment: Private is private.  If you need to call it outside the class, it has to be public. Or make it protected and extend a subclass to which `otherFunction()`  belongs

Comment: I too encourage that you pay attention to both comments given above.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with PHP 5.3 yes this is possible.

It's called Reflection.  For your needs you want ReflectionMethod

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php

Here's an example

```
<?php

//  example.php
include 'myclass.php';

$MyClass = new MyClass();

//  throws SPL exception if display doesn't exist
$display = new ReflectionMethod($MyClass, 'display');

//  lets us invoke private and protected methods
$display->setAccesible(true);
    
//  calls the method
$display->invoke();

}
```

Obviously you'll want to wrap this in a try/catch block to ensure the exception gets handled.